# SFML drawing text causes crash?

Tags: c++, sfml

```
   #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    sf::Text test;
    test.setString("Hello world");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("Monospace.ttf");
    test.setFont(font);

    // Start the game loop
    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                app.close();
        }

        // Clear screen
        app.clear();

        // Draw the sprite
        app.draw(test);

        // Update the window
        app.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is just a quick example I've thrown together. By all rights this should just work. But for some reason I just get a crash, everytime. If I comment out setFont, there is no crash. If I comment out the draw, there is no crash.

Running debug gives me the following error:

```
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In ?? () (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig4icd32.dll)"
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts as to why this is happening.

Comment: Start by adding checks for IO errors. In particular,  here `loadFromFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be an issue with outdated hardware. I bought a new laptop and this was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on font loading. Though it doesn't crash for me, it doesn't successfully load the font, so at least:

```
if (font.loadFromFile(FONTDIR "Monospace.ttf"))
    test.setFont(font);
```

In my case I had to supply it full paths to make it work:

```
if (font.loadFromFile(FONTDIR "Monospace.ttf")
 || font.loadFromFile(FONTDIR "liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf"))
{
    test.setFont(font);
}
```

Where I #define the FONTDIR as on my system:

```
#define FONTDIR "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/"
```

Now it pans out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you'd have lost that bet. Still immediately crashes. It seems to load as it does execute ```test.setFont(font);```

Comment: So, when _does_ it crash?

Comment: It crashes at ```app.draw(test);``` However, if the font does not load, it does not crash.

Comment: Could it be that you have a faulty font? Perhaps you have a version of libfreetype installed that isn't ABI compatible or lacks important fixes/

Comment: Consider building/installing the relevant debug libraries and running with valgrind/ASAN/UBSan to find the exact cause

Comment: If all else fails, take the info in this answer as indication that another system doesn't show the same crash, at least not unconditionally

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code on my machine and it works just fine. I think you need to check if you have linked all the library dependencies correctly. For example, in the case of Fonts you need to have "freetype.lib" in your linker dependencies in the correct order. Here's a link to the [official SFML setup guide](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php) and a picture to the correct order of dependencies.

[image]

Comment: But I don't link statically. Would this still be an issue?

Comment: Yes. I use dynamic linking as well and I still need to include this.

Comment: So, let me elaborate. You're correct to think it shouldn't matter as I believe that to be the case as well. However, for some reason when I switched from code::blocks to MSVS it just didn't work like that. I had to include it to fix the issue. I'm not sure about the exact reason for this but it worked for me at the time. It's possible your issue is something else so try hitting the devs up on the SFML forums.

Comment: I already asked there. They don't seem able to help. I'll try your solution though.

Comment: Nope, that's not doing it either. I'm absolutely lost on this one, and it's such a simple thing.

Comment: @RiverreedWard I feel kind of lost too since the exact code is working on my machine. Maybe it's an issue with the font file that you're using? Try using another font. This is quite a bizarre thing to happen if I'm being honest.

Comment: I already tried several different fonts. Some download online, others from the default fonts available with windows.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of some workaround? Is there some 3rd party library I can plug into the application to display text?

Comment: Sorry but I don't. I have never really used something external with sfml. More like I never needed to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the `Monospace.ttf` file in the executing directory?

```
font.loadFromFile("Monospace.ttf");
```

This means look for `Monospace.ttf` in the current directory where you start the executable. I don't have your exact font so I tried with another. If you have the file, but it still doesn't work, then the font might be corrupted. Try to open the `.ttf` file in your OS's font viewer and see if it loads.

[image]